# Trigger raiseerror function incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, triggers

I have trigger & inside code is:

```
declare    
    @errno int,
    @errmsg varchar(255),

if exists (select 1
           from audit t2, inserted i1, deleted d1
           where t2.user_id = d1.cpi_id
             and (i1.cpi_id != d1.cpi_id))
begin
    select 
        @errno = 30005,
        @errmsg = 'Children still exist in "audit". Cannot modify parent code in "cpi_user".'
       goto error
end

/*  Errors handling  */
error:
    raiserror @errno @errmsg
    rollback  transaction
```

When I execute this, I get this error

> Incorrect syntax near '@errno'

Weird thing is, same code was working before & suddenly it's showing an error.

Can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: may be `set` instead of `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Its because `@errno` can be varchar and quotes are not there surrounding 30005.

Please try to check with :

```
 select @errno  = '30005',
              @errmsg = 'Children still exist in "audit". Cannot modify parent code in "cpi_user".'
```

**EDIT 1 :**

It may be because extra comma after :

```
@errmsg varchar(255),
```

While declaration.

No need of that comma.

**Edit 2:**

You have written :

```
Declare @errno int,
@errmsg varchar(255),
................
```

Please write it as :

```
Declare @errno int
Declare @errmsg varchar(255)
```

Comment: I will try with this. but still i have one question. same code was working fine before & not now. so, have u any idea?

Comment: same things happen with me ("same code was working before") ...but things are not as we think :)

Comment: Hi...I check @errno is int.so, i think 3005 is right. i made modification on question.

Comment: hhmm...i got it. but i have many variable declaration. so, i think comma should be come.

Comment: ohh...then let me see more carefully.. If you solves the matter plz let me know at that point .

Comment: Hi Bro...finally i resolve it by "raiserror (@errno, @errmsg,1) " this syntex.Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Kvadiyatar ohh... Thats gr8 ... congo :)

Answer (score 0):

syntax for Raiserror:

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
    { ,severity ,state }
    [ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
    [ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

In your case:

```
raiserror (30005,
           1, --Severety 
           10, --State
   'Children still exist in "audit". Cannot modify parent code in "cpi_user".')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mispelling.

It's not RAISEERROR, it's RAISERROR.

Otherwise you will get:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'RAISEERROR'
```

And you also need 3 parameters.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogError
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO dbo.DB_Errors
        VALUES (
            SUSER_SNAME()
            ,ERROR_NUMBER()
            ,ERROR_STATE()
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY()
            ,ERROR_LINE()
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE()
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ,GETDATE()
            );

        DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            ,@Severity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
            ,@State SMALLINT = ERROR_STATE() 

        RAISERROR(@Message, @Severity, @State)
    END
    GO
```